# Create the new tag [ice-protocol]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I was reading some questions about WebRTC (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686707/webrtc-stun-based-connexions-suddenly-stopped-working), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539321/computing-foundations-for-candidate-in-interactive-connectivity-establishment-i), etc.). All of those questions are tagged with the [ice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ice) tag.

According to its info :

> According to ZeroC, the developers of Ice (Internet Communications
> Engine);
>
> > (Ice) is a modern distributed computing platform with support for C++,
> > .NET, Java, Python, Objective-C, Ruby, PHP, and ActionScript. Ice is
> > used in mission-critical projects by companies all over the world.
>
> Ice is cross-platform, supports multiple language bindings and is
> open-sourced under the GPL.

However in the WebRTC field, ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment) is a [protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) used to choose the best path between two users (even with NAT or Firewall issues). ([Wikipedia's ice page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment)). Nothing to do with the current tag.

Should we create a new tag, for example [ice-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ice-protocol), and retag all of those questions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and added the tag as they are using [ice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ice) for an incorrect use.  The new tag is [ice-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ice-protocol).  I added a brief excerpt and wiki but fell free to add to it once it is open.